# 1D time dependent mass transfer and reaction in a very small gas filter

Tags: matlab, modeling, pde

I am trying to model a PDE including advection-diffusion and reaction terms. I want to see the concentration profile after a long time (2*60*60 sec) in a very tiny slab (5 micrometer). I used method of line (`ode15s`) to solve this PDE but my result does not match with the experimental result. Because the outlet concentration gets maximum concentration right away (as can be seen in my plot). Does anybody have a suggestion?

[image: PDE and figures]

```
clc
clear 
close all
%%%%%%%%%%%parameters%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
global a b  g  Ki dx cin

Lf=5e-6;     %microM
dm=8.6*10^-6;   %m2/min

area=0.65;       % m^-1
cin=20; % 
ki=1;           %mg/m3 min
Ki=0.24;        %m3/mg
ux=0.5;       %m/min
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%constant%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
a=dm;
b=ux;
g=ki*Ki;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
tf=2*60*60;
nx=50;
xf=Lf;
dx=xf/nx;
nt=1000;
dt=tf/nt;

x = 0:dx:xf;
t = 0:dt:tf;
N = numel(x);
u0 = zeros(N,1);
y0 = u0 ;

[t,y] = ode15s(@(t,y)fun(t,y,x,N),t,y0);
u = y(:,1:2:end);
x = (1:N)/(N+1);
plot(t/60,u(:,end))

function dydt=fun(~,y,~,N)
  global a b  g dx cin
  bc=cin;
  dydt = zeros(N,1);
  i = 1;
  dydt(i,:)=a*(y(i+1,:)-2*y(i,:)+bc)/(dx^2)-b*(y(i+1,:)-bc)./(2*dx)-g.*y(i+1,:);

  i = 2:N-1;
  dydt(i,:)=a*(y(i+1,:)-2*y(i,:)+y(i-1,:))/(dx^2)-b*(y(i+1,:)-y(i-1,:))./(2*dx)-g.*y(i,:);

  i = N;
  dydt(i,:)=a*(y(N,:)-2*y(i,:)+y(i-1,:))/(dx^2)-b*(y(N,:)-y(i-1,:))./(2*dx)-g.*y(i,:);

end
```

Comment: The posted code does not work and produces errors. Do you mind sharing the correct code that you used to get that plot?

Comment: I have ran this code in matlab v.2017 and it works for me.i dont know why it doesn'r work in your system.i run this pde in several ways but i got the same result as this plot.  @Aziz

Comment: Sorry about that. It actually works. I think I had a copy-paste issue. As for the output, I ran your code with a small time `tf=2e-6`, and I got the same curve you're trying to reproduce. It seems that your discretization is correct, but you have incorrect coefficients or mismatching units.

Comment: in this PDE, diffusion term has dominant effect, so let say ux=0 again diffusivity unit is m^2/s and after long time the curve would not change. diffusivity is correct number for toluene. i dont know where is my mistake.